# Can you eliminate La Guardia Airport and still move same amount of NYC passengers by air, but faster?

Tags: united-states, aviation

Joel Spolsky (I think) made this claim on latest [Stack <strike>Exchange</strike> Overflow podcast](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Stack-Overflow-Podcast-97-Where-did-you-get-that-hat/) that you can eliminate La Guardia airport in NYC, and even if 100% of La Guardia flyers started using the remaining two airports (JFK/Newark), that would allow to fly them in/out faster, presumably due to less-complicated air traffic control situation.

Is that claim backed up by some reliable study?

Comment: I think [this speculation](http://freakonomics.com/2009/05/14/want-to-fix-new-york-air-congestion-shut-down-laguardia/) is what started this idea (2009).